# how to set the required validator for an input field in jquery?

Tags: validation, input

I have a page which has a GridView placed in an update panel. Each row in the GridView has a update button, when clicked, a modal dialog will pop up, where you could edit the corresponding row and save the record to the database through a web service call.  Following is the aspx and jquery code. My question is I want to make the txtName and txtDescription required. As you can see, the Save button in the modal dialog gets created in the jquery function. How should I add required field validator to those fields? And when the user clicking the Save button, if the txtName or txtDescription is empty, a red label with text “required!” will should next to it, the focus will set to the first field that is empty.

```
<div id="dvMainContainer">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMainPanel" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <table summary="content" id="Table3">
                    <tr> 
                        <td>   
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                                AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="20" 
                                onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div><input type="button" value="update" /></div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField >
                                    <HeaderTemplate>Vendor<br />
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVendor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnVendorChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="- Select a Vendor -" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Vendor") %></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" >
                                    <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Name")%></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" >
                                    <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Description")%></ItemTemplate>                
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dvUpdatePrompt" style="display: none;" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Vendor:</td>
                <td><select name="VendorList" id="VendorList"></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtDescription"/></td>             
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    this.BindEvents = function () {
        var myself = this;

        $(myself.get_element()).find("input[value='update']").each(
            function () {
                var input = $(this);

                if (input.closest('tr').find('td')[1].innerText.replace('&nbsp;', '') != '') {
                    input.click(
                        function () {
                            myself.UpdateButtonClicked(this);
                        }
                    );
                }
                else {
                    input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        );
    }
    this.UpdateButtonClicked = function (button) {
        var myself = this;
        var btns = {};
        var Vendor = "";
        var Name = "";
        var Description = "";

        …
        btns["Save"] = function () {
            myself.UpdateVendor(button);                   
        };

        btns["Cancel"] = function () { $("#dvUpdatePrompt").dialog('close'); };

        …
        $("#dvUpdatePrompt").dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: btns,
            width: 500,
            height: 300
        });
    }

    this.UpdateVendor = function (button) {
        var myself = this;

        …
        var parmIn = "…";

        myself.Utilities.CallWebService('WebService.asmx/UpateVendor', parmIn,
            function (result) {
                $("#dvUpdatePrompt").dialog('close');
                ...
            }
        );
    }
```

Update: I added following code to the this.BindEvents function: But it is not working?

```
$("#txtName").blur(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).parents('p').addClass('warning');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Add `class="required"`? How about `required="true"`? If you were using [this plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), that would be the case.

Comment: I tried required="true", it showed me an error saying required is not valid attribute of input.

Comment: What about `class="required"`? Then you could just add a small routine that iterates through anything with that class to see if it has a value or is empty.

Comment: nope. it is not working either